# Can i use foreign key to unique constraint in EF6?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I know this question had been proposed and I've read the following links about my question:

[Entity Framework foreign keys to non-primary key fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435065/foreign-key-to-non-primary-key)

[Entity Framework Code First - Foreign Key to non primary key field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488300/entity-framework-code-first-foreign-key-to-non-primary-key-field)

but I want to know is this case (foreign key to unique constraint) still not supported in EF6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matter still is not supported in EF6. in the other words you can not use foreign key to unique constraint in entity framework 6.